# Using git hooks to add a txt file to the last merge commit?

Tags: git, hook

How do I add a modified text file to the last merge commit.
I have a text file in which I write the text of the merge commit.
I want this file to get into this commit, i use a hook post-merge, but i get error "fatal: You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend".
Is there a hook that triggers after the merge is committed?

Comment: You won't be able to insert anything in previous commit. What you can do is to create a *new* commit to replace it. That's why you can't (for instance, since I don't know if that's part of what you want) use the commit hash in its own message.

Comment: How can I programmatically wait for the merge commit to complete in order to create a new commit?

Comment: *Do not* do this. Hooks should not modify what is to be committed. If you need to modify what is to be committed, do that by running a command other than `git XXX`. (This isn't a technical issue, it's a "don't surprise the programmers" opinion.)

Comment: Is the text file only for specifying the merge commit message, or do you also want the text file to be stored in a file in the merge commit? If the latter, what is the purpose of the text file after the commit message is written?

Comment: @TTT, hello. We want to store a commit message to history.txt file without mandatory of manual filling this file.